# Where is Windows pulling this connection status/type from and can I edit it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, connection

In the list of network connections I have, the LAN connection has a value of 'EData' where others have 'Not connected' or 'Unidentified network'.

[image: Network connections]

This seems to be the status or type of connection, but I'm not sure where it pulled this value from, or if I can change it.

The PC is not on a domain and the workgroup is the default 'WORKGROUP'.

'EData' was the name of the SSID on our wireless network for a while, but this isn't used on this PC and indeed the wireless adapter is disabled.

Anyone know where this value is derived from and if it can be edited?

It's not a big issue but things like this make me curious to see if they can be 'fixed'!

Comment: I think it could be the name of the domain or workgroup your computer is a member of? Right click My Computer and choose Properties then look under the *Computer name, domain and workgroup settings* section.

Comment: Sorry, should've clarified this. PC is not on a domain and the workgroup is 'WORKGROUP'.

Comment: I believe it could be related to DNS suffix settings on your IPv4 or IPv6 settings. Right click **Local Area Connection** and choose Properties. Click on **Internet Protocol v4 (TCP/IPv4)**. Click the **Advanced** button. Click the **DNS** tab and check for a **DNS suffix for this connection**. Also check the IPv6 settings in the same way. I wouldn't change them unless you need to though.

Comment: There are no DNS suffixes listed, nor have I ever had cause to change any of these settings.

Answer (score 0):

This can be changed in the "Network and Sharing Center" > Choose "Manage Networks" from the left pane of the window > Now, you have the list of adapters, where you can rename it by right clicking the adapter.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I had to re-enable the wireless adapter and could change this value, but even after doing this the old name stuck with both the wireless and wired connection. Can't reboot now to test what might happen then, and this still doesn't explain why Windows would make a wired connection inherit a wireless network name.

Comment: Nope, even after two reboots the connection (and, bizarrely, the renamed wireless connection) still show 'EData'.

Comment: Check any registry entry for 'EData' and delete it. Please note that, take a backup of your registry and delete the entry.

Answer (score 0):

Found the following registry key via search

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
```

and some asscoaited `WPadNetworkName` entries that referred to the 'EData' name. Changed them and nothing happened. Disabled the wireless adapter and voilà, the name snapped to the new one I'd entered in the registry.

I suspect a reboot would also have triggered the refresh of the names once it had been changed in the registry.

Still no closer to understanding the mechanism or purpose of this inheritance, but that's Windows for you I guess.

Comment: Perhaps your network uses a proxy and Windows is getting the description from there? WPAD is an automatic proxy detection protocol.

Comment: No proxies here. I think the key thing was the NetworkList\Profiles, the Wpad settings are just populated with the same value if not explicitly set?